# Rules to evaluate Suprema and Infima

Tags: analysis, functions

Note: All functions considered are supposed to be bounded.

Nowhere I found rules to evaluate suprema and infima. Obviously,
$$ 
 c \cdot \sup_{x\in \mathbb R} f(x) = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} cf(x) \quad\mbox{and}\quad
 \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} ( f(x) + c) = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} f(x) + c. 
$$
Further I suppose if $f : \mathbb R \to [0,\infty), g : \mathbb R \to [0,\infty)$, then
$$
 \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} (f(x) - g(x)) \ge \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} f(x) - \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} g(x)
$$
for if $x \in \mathbb R$ then
\begin{align*}
 \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} (f(x) - g(x)) + \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} g(x)
  & = \sup_{x\in\mathbb R}(f(x) - g(x) + \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} g(x)) \\
  & \ge \sup_{x\in\mathbb R} f(x) \\ 
\end{align*}
where we used the non-negativity in $\sup_{x} g(x) - g(x) \ge 0$, which yields the relation. Also for $f(x) = \max(0,1-x^2), g(x) = \min(\max(0,x),2))$ we have $\sup (f(x) - g(x)) = 2, \sup f(x) = 1, \sup g(x) = 2$.

Also for functions $f, g : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ we have
$$
 \inf f(x) + \inf g(x) \le f(x) + g(x) \le \sup f(x) + \sup g(x)
$$
and
$$
 \inf f(x) - \sup g(x) \le f(x) - g(x) \le \sup f(x) - \inf g(x)
$$
which yield:
\begin{align*}
 \inf f(x) + \inf g(x) & \le \inf (f(x) + g(x)) \\
 \inf f(x) - \sup g(x) & \le \inf (f(x) + g(x)) \\
 \sup (f(x) + g(x)) & \le \sup f(x) + \sup g(x) \\
 \sup (f(x) - g(x)) & \le \sup f(x) - \inf g(x).
\end{align*}

Other results I found: for $f : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ bounded, we have
$$
 \inf_x \sup_y f(x,y) \ge \sup_y \inf_x f(x,y)
$$
because for each $x \in \mathbb R^2$ we have $f(x,y) \ge \inf_z f(z,y)$ and
so $\sup_y f(x,y) \ge \sup_y \inf_z f(z,y)$, and because this holds for any x, we get
$\inf_z \sup_y f(z,y) \ge \sup_y \inf_z f(z,y)$.

Here my Questions:

1) Are my proofs correct?

2) Are there any other results?

3) Are there results related to sets alone (for example how behaves suprema/infima
and the [Minkowski sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of sets)?